# Beginner want's to add button function to a night vision PiCamera

Tags: raspbian, python, picamera, switches

I want to add button functions to my night vision PiCamera. I have a custom script that outputs the screen to spilt screen because I want to make night vision goggles with it.
`

```
from picamera import mmalobj as mo, mmal
from signal import pause

camera = mo.MMALCamera()
splitter = mo.MMALSpiltter()
render_l = mo.MMALRenderer()
redner_r = mo.MMALRenderer()

camera.outputs[0].framesize = (420,240)
camera.outputs[0].framesize = 30
camera.outputs[0].commit()

p = render_l.inputs[0].params[mmal.MMAL_PARAMETER_DISPLAYREGION]
p.set = mmal.MMAL_DISPLAY_SET_FULLSCREEN | mmal.MMAL_DISPLAY_SET_DEST_RECT`
p.fullscreen = False
p.dest_rect = mmal.MMAL_RECT_T(0, 180, 420, 240)
render_l.inputs[0].params[mmal.MMAL_PARAMETER_DISPLAYREGION] = p
p.dest_rect = mmal.MMAL_RECT_T(420, 180, 420, 240)
render_r.inputs[0].params[mmal.MMAL_PARAMETER_DISPLAYREGION] = p

splitter.connect(camera.outputs[0])
render_l.connect(splitter.outputs[0])
render_r.connect(splitter.outputs[1])

splitter.enable()
render_l.enable()
render_r.enable()
pause()
```

I would like the button to capture an image and record a video, anybody know how? (using raspberry pi 4)

Comment: What have you tried to capture an image or record a video? I ask because your question strikes me as a bit "open-ended", which may lead to general (rather than specific) answers. The [Help section](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) here is worth reviewing, and in particular, the topic of ["How to Ask a Good Question"](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) offers specific advice on how to scope your question to improve your prospects for getting a useful answer.

Comment: `anybody know how?` is not a question about your project ... please ask a clear, answerable question about the project ... what good is it to you if I answer `yes`?

Comment: To add a button you might want to look at the recipe from [GPIO Zero](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/recipes.html#button). Have a go and if you are still having problems, then update your question with what you have done.